# What temperature to set a cooling system for a arudunio?

Tags: arduino, hardware

I'm building a cosplay prop for a friend that uses an arudunio Uno. The UNO will be kept inside a black PVC box with little ventilation and taken to comic cons. So it's going to get hot at times. I've never really built gaming PCs or anything with batteries and I'm not sure what temperatures are ideal to run at so my guesses are just based on a google search.

My question is:

If I place a temperature sensor next to the UNO and program it to start a fan at a given temperature, What temperature would be a good choice?

I was thinking 35 degrees with an alarm going off at 70 degrees telling him to turn it off.

Also, there will be two other batteries one 3.7V Li ion phone battery that powers the chips and a small audio amp with a 18-volt (May change) drill battery powering a DC motor. Both in different locations.

For this, I was thinking I would set a larger fan to start at 30 degrees with an alarm at 55.

FYI this will be programmed on a separate ATTINY chip.

Comment: What's this UNO going to be doing that's causing it to get that hot?  Not much current should be going through anything on the Arduino board itself, so if that chip is getting hot you have a larger issue on your hands.  If there are other components that are getting hot then ventilation should be centered around those, not the Arduino.

Comment: build it, and see which temperatures you're going to reach. This cannot be answered. The MCU is rated for up to 125°C. Arduino Uno's operating temperature is up to 85°C. If you even get near those values power design is very bad. this is a software community btw. your question is off-topic

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because is about hardware design

Comment: it's mostly the drill battery that's causing issues. However, the ambient temperature around the UNO is also just hot. It's in a black box that just absorbs heat. I'd move it outside but that defeats the illusion of the cosplay. I had extra components to make a second cooling system for it so I figured why not protect it from summer heat?

Comment: so you prefer adding an entire cooling system with fans and whatnot over moving the battery to another location? if your battery dies from the summer heat, the person inside the costume is most likely dead already. we usually perform worse in hot environments than electronics.

Comment: Downvoting becase OP didn't answer what this Arduino was doing that is making it so hot.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend keeping it **below 125C *maximum*** (that is the ATmega 328p's maximum temperature rating). However, I have never seen an UNO get that hot. If you are concerned though, aim for as cool as possible with a *maximum* temperature of about **80C**